# Update_layout argument list with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am learning to use Plotly and in every single example the layout is updated with fig.update_layout(...

https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/

And I would like to know exactly everything which is possible to do there.

Where could I find the exhaustive argument list for

```
fig.update_layout( ???
```

Comment: You can find it in the Plotly documentation: https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout.

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, 'update layout', you can update alot of things with it.

Check out: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34693508)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily compute :

```
fig.update_layout(
        title=title,
        xaxis_title=xaxis,
        yaxis_title=yaxis)
```

where title, xaxis_title and yaxis_title are strings.